# Curve fitting function suggested from Zunzun is not working

Tags: python, curve-fitting, data-fitting

I am trying to fit a dataset. To find a fit equation that suits to the dataset I applied the ZunZun function finder. this delivered me the following match:

[ZunZun equation finder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xts3d.png)

After receiving a fit equation I tried to fit it to my dataset as follows:

fit function definition:

```
def fit_logfirst(x, A, B, C, D, E):


   return A * (1.0 -(1.0 + (x/B)**C)**(-1.0 * D)) + E

popt, pcov = scipy.optimize.curve_fit(fit_logfirst,X12,Ynorm12)
A,B,C,D,E = popt
print((A, B, C, D, E))

plt.plot(X12, Ynorm12)
plt.title("pH value")
plt.xlabel('time')
plt.ylabel('pH-value')

y_log = fit_logfirst(X12,A,B,C,D,E)
plt.plot(X12,y_log,'--', color='red')
plt.show()


print(popt)
errors = [np.sqrt(pcov[i][i]) for i in range(0, len(pcov))]
print("a = {:.2f} +- {:.2f}".format(popt[0],errors[0]))
print("b = {:.2f} +- {:.2f}".format(popt[1],errors[1]))
print("c = {:.2f} +- {:.2f}".format(popt[2],errors[2]))
print("d = {:.2f} +- {:.2f}".format(popt[3],errors[3]))


residuals1 = Ynorm12 - fit_logfirst(X12, *popt)
ss_res1 = np.sum(residuals1**2)
ss_tot1=np.sum((Ynorm12-np.mean(Ynorm12))**2)
r_sqared1 = 1-(ss_res1/ss_tot1)
print(r_sqared1)
```

where my dataset is

X12:

```
[3.80666249 3.87120101 3.93182563 4.00733319 4.06044301 4.11087386 4.17438727 4.21950771 4.26267988 4.31748811 4.35670883 4.39444915 4.44265126 4.47733681 4.51085951 4.54329478 4.58496748 4.61512052 4.6443909 4.68213123 4.7095302  4.73619845 4.77068462 4.79579055 4.82028157 4.85203026 4.87519732 4.8978398  4.91998093 4.94875989 4.9698133  4.99043259 5.01727984 5.0369526 5.05624581 5.08140436 5.09986643 5.11799381 5.13579844 5.1590553  5.17614973 5.19295685 5.21493576 5.23110862 5.24702407 5.26785816 5.28320373 5.29831737 5.31811999 5.33271879 5.34710753 5.36129217 5.37989735 5.39362755 5.40717177 5.42495002 5.43807931 5.45103845 5.46806014 5.48063892 5.49306144 5.50938834 5.52146092 5.53338949 5.54517744 5.56068163 5.57215403 5.58349631 5.59842196 5.6094718  5.62040087 5.6347896 5.6454469  5.65599181 5.66642669 5.68017261 5.69035945 5.700443575.71373281 5.7235851  5.73334128 5.74620319 5.75574221 5.7651911 5.77765232 5.78689738 5.79605775 5.80513497 5.81711116 5.82600011 5.83481074 5.84643878 5.85507192 5.86363118 5.87493073 5.88332239 5.89164421 5.90263333 5.91079664 5.91889385 5.92692603 5.93753621 5.94542061 5.95324333 5.96357934 5.97126184 5.97888576 5.98896142 5.99645209 6.00388707 6.01371516 6.02102335 6.02827852]
```

Ynorm12:

```
[1.98354223 1.98253419 1.97986644 1.97547433 1.96942583 1.96142593 1.9519082  1.9412507  1.92847927 1.91454564 1.89907719 1.88108696 1.86154084 1.84127724 1.81943684 1.80090491 1.77693861 1.751196 1.72269096 1.69519017 1.67833515 1.66304758 1.64963417 1.63806646 1.62877018 1.62133728 1.61608436 1.6131826  1.61243913 1.61328029 1.61592232 1.62066409 1.62731662 1.62461665 1.62042886 1.61769843 1.61481399 1.61690314 1.61575251 1.61496915 1.61333398 1.61104492 1.60999359 1.6084093  1.60671998 1.60596056 1.60485361 1.60397158 1.60321664 1.60185624 1.60069411 1.59919805 1.59785275 1.59623165 1.59509498 1.59398714 1.59292277 1.59153009 1.59029068 1.58883309 1.58702818 1.58525328 1.58351393 1.58181564 1.58016394 1.57940324 1.57786456 1.5763955  1.57622329 1.57620592 1.57597518 1.57619345 1.57646696 1.57635812 1.57625041 1.57581972 1.57548344 1.57558614 1.57573091 1.57553655 1.57533483 1.57513469 1.57494505 1.57443905 1.5743671  1.57393184 1.57313049 1.57271067 1.57193418 1.57154865 1.57068139 1.56938595 1.56887692 1.56789516 1.56730023 1.56671182 1.56613607 1.56557912 1.56424109 1.56291703 1.56241292 1.56146965 1.56094678 1.56046398 1.55969164 1.55857136 1.5574896  1.55605991 1.55521949 1.55496835 1.55445308 1.55414391 1.55404085]
```

But by applying this I only receive this:

[python fit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EQeOZ.png)

Do you have any guess why this is not working? Would be happy for any input on that, so thanks in advance!

Comment: What did `print((A, B, C, D, E))` produce?

Comment: for that I got [7.76114476e-01 1.30631104e-10 6.41652402e-01 1.10213455e+00
 8.68032917e-01]

Comment: Did you implement `fit_logfirst` correctly? Did you test it?

Comment: strange function....what about `a * x + b - c * ( x - x0 ) / sqrt( 1 + d * ( x - x0 )**2 )` or similar? Or `a * x + b - c * tanh( d * ( x - x0 )`

Comment: I will try it and let you know if it works! Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: If you believe you have implemented your function correctly then this is not a programming question, it is a maths question.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the OP is asking why the function/equation used for the curve fit is deficient - OP states that the function is implemented correctly.

Answer (score 0):

@wwii yes I think so, with random parameter and x values from 0 to 10 I get this curve for fit_logfirst:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sUIGS.png)

Comment: please don't post comments as answers.